# Prevents HTTP method in spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm using spring-data-rest.

Given following repository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

The annotation `@RestResource(exported = false)` on the `save()` method makes the framework return a `405 Method Not Allowed` error when using methods POST, PUT and PATCH.

My question : How can I just return a 405 error on PUT method while POST and PATCH are still allowed for this repository ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

@SWiggels
Thanks for your response :)
Your solution didn't work for me... PUT is always allowed.

For others I found this one that worked :

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class MyEntityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myentity/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> preventsPut() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```

Comment: You indeed need to override the default behavior of the PUT handler. You should also add a custom handler for OPTIONS as shown by @SWiggels so as to improve the discoverability of your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your allowed methods in the response of the options-probe.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
 ResponseEntity<Void> getProposalsOptions() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAllow(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(OPTIONS, PATCH, POST)));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

This allows only `Options, Patch, Post` as request-methods. For every other tried method you get a HTTP-405-Error.

Comment: Your solution assigns _OPTIONS, PATCH, POST_ to the _Allow_ header of the response, but it does not forbid other methods.